# Python parse string in span class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've already tried the other solutions but did not work.
Here is my span tag:

```
<span class="DFlfde SwHCTb" data-precision="2" data-value="7.0498">7,05</span>
```

and here is my full code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#<span class="DFlfde SwHCTb" data-precision="2" data-value="7.0498">7,05</span>
url = "https://www.google.com/search?q={}+kaç+tl".format(input())
r = requests.get(url)
source = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html")
print(source.find_all("span",string="DFlfde SwHCTb"))
```

It returns a empty list, i need the value "7.05", how can i reach it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things to do to get your data:

1. specify `User-Agent` header (google needs this to return correct data)
2. in `.find_all` specify `class_=` parameter, **not** `string`

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=100+kaç+tl"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0'}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
source = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
print(source.find_all("span", class_="DFlfde SwHCTb"))

# or

print(source.select_one('span.DFlfde.SwHCTb').text)
```

Prints:

```
[<span class="DFlfde SwHCTb" data-precision="2" data-value="13.0095">13,01</span>]
13,01
```